# Add a jump to or go to specific page in a Laravel pagination with search

Tags: php, laravel, pagination

I have a Laravel pagination for search result . I can go prev/next page or first/last page.But i want to go a specific page based on input value.

Here is the link image.

[image]

I need some idea how to do it keeping the search result.

Comment: Have you tried anything??

Comment: Yes , pagination is implemented ,but  I am stuck in this specific issue , need some idea.

Comment: You should add to your url param "page=n" where "n" is the number from the input

Comment: But when I submit " Go To " the search parameters are lost

Answer (score 0):

If you are adding a page parameter with your request with page number, Laravel will resolve your page; like you have user page

```
example.com/user?page=2 // will resolve page 2


example.com/user?page=n // will resolve page n
```

Comment: But when I submit " Go To " the search parameters are lost

Comment: then you have to add the  "GO TO" button click script with the question.